# How to get rid of "SD Card blank or has unsupported filesystem" notification

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd

My Samsung Galaxy S II phone crashed and after I restarted it, there was an SD card notification icon that says "SD Card blank or has unsupported filesystem" with the only option of formatting the card.

However, <del>the contents of the SD card like photos taken or videos is accessible just fine</del> **UPDATE: the card seems to be corrupt, at least it's not visible from my computer.** I'll try formatting it.

Comment: I'd try: shut down, remove the card, start up without it, wait 5 minutes, shut down, insert the card, and start up again.

Comment: To my surprise, when I removed the card I can still browse both /sdcard and /sdcard/external_sd paths from the built-in file explorer. What is going on? What's the filesystem path for external SD?

Comment: /sdcard is the path to the internal storage on the device. and /sdcard/external_sd is the external, but if you dont have a card in there, then it is just a "folder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SD Card blank or has unsupported filesystem** means your SD Card has corrupted data.

The only way is to get it normal is to Format it.

**Now what about the Data on SD Card ?**
If you are using Linux Machine then there is something called [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Install it on your PC. Now connect your phone with SD Card inserted to you PC. Run TestDisk and follow the options that it shows. Backup the Uncorrupted Data to your PC and format the SD Card from your Phone.

Comment: Formatting the card wasn't possible as it was probably corrupted but I managed to copy data from it using the TestDisk software, thanks.