# USB storage blank or unsupported filesystem

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-peripherals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of “SD Card blank or has unsupported filesystem” notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14023/how-to-get-rid-of-sd-card-blank-or-has-unsupported-filesystem-notification)

When I connect a USB Flash drive to my Galaxy SII Android 2.3.4, it alerts me with this message:

> USB Storage Blank or Has Unsupported Filesystem

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: BTW Please delete your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428205/usb-storage-black-or-unsupported-files-galaxy-s-ii-android-2-3-4?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) from StackOverflow, as cross-posting is frowned upon. :)

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1734698&page=1

Comment: Simple advice: format your card to fat32.

Comment: Thanks to all i will look at the other posts ,also delete my question over there in stackoverflow and i will also format it as fat 32 thanks a lot to all of you i will feed you back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing you can do is first try and get anything off the drive you want from a computer.
Then reformat the drive to FAT32 and try connecting it again if your still getting the error report back

Comment: ok i will see it through

Comment: Done and Worked Perfect :)